# Python dynamic size of integer arguments into list

Tags: python, list, dynamic-variables

I am having an issue with putting a dynamic number of arguments into a list, then being able to access them later. Here is the code. I am passing arguments such as '2,3,4,5'

```
def puesdoPrime(*args):
    from string import ascii_lowercase
    primeInput = []
    print "puesdoPrime not yet implemeneted"
    for arg in args:
        primeInput.append(arg)

    for i in primeInput:
        print "primeInput value are %i" % primeInput[i]
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "homework3.py", line 41, in <module>
    main()  
  File "homework3.py", line 34, in main
    puesdoPrime(printInput)
  File "homework3.py", line 15, in puesdoPrime
    print "primeInput value are %i" % primeInput[i]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple
```

This is how the function is being called:

```
userInput = input()
    if userInput == 1:
        print "What numbers do you want to find that are simultaneously Puesdo Prime?"
        printInput = input()
        puesdoPrime(printInput)
```

Any help would be very much appreciated in helping solve this.

Comment: can You add line where this function is called

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `for i in primeInput` will loop over the values of your list, not the indices.  So you would want to change your second `for` loop to the following:

```
for item in primeInput:
    print "primeInput value are %i" % item
```

Or to loop over the indices:

```
for i in range(len(primeInput)):
    print "primeInput value are %i" % primeInput[i]
```

It would also help to see how you are calling `puesdoPrime()`, but to use `*args` correctly your call should look something like the following:

```
puesdoPrime(2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Or if you have an existing collection of arguments:

```
the_args = (2, 3, 4, 5)
puesdoPrime(*the_args)
```

Without the `*` in the previous code you would only be passing a single argument which would be a four element tuple.

As a side note, I think you mean "pseudo", not "puesdo".

Comment: Adding the * before the passed values worked perfectly along with your first suggestion on looping through the values. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Or maybe "puesto", like something which works as a prime for a living? Or "puedo", like a prime that reigns over other primes? :)